# How can I show the results of each step in a pipeline of continuous transformations without looping?

Tags: bash, pipe

Consider the following example Bash one-liner in which the letters "h", "e" and "o" are removed from the word "hello" one at a time, in that order. Only the two "l" letters remain;

```
$ echo "hello" | tr -d h | tr -d e | tr -d o
ll
```

I am trying to find a method for displaying the output of each command to the screen within the one liner, so others running it can see what is going on. Continuing with the above example I would like output as follows;

```
$ echo "hello" | tr -d h | tr -d e | tr -d o
hello
ello
llo
ll
```

Is this possible? As per the operation of the one-liner above, we are carrying the output from command to command with the vertical pipe. So I assume I would have to break from the pipe to print to stdout, which would then interrupt the "command chain" I have written. <strike>Or perhaps `tee` can be used here, but I can't seem to achieve the desire affect.</strike> **UPDATE**: `tee` won't work because it's output is still within the boundaries of the pipe, duh!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This only works on a terminal:

```
echo hello  | tee /dev/tty |
    tr -d h | tee /dev/tty |
    tr -d e | tee /dev/tty |
    tr -d o
```

The `/dev/tty` device redirects output to the current terminal, no matter where the normal output goes.

Answer (score 4):

You can `tee` the output directly to the terminal:

```
echo hello  | tee /proc/$$/fd/1 |
    tr -d h | tee /proc/$$/fd/1 |
    tr -d e | tee /proc/$$/fd/1 |
    tr -d o
```

`$$` is the shell's PID.

Comment: Note, this depends on your system having the `/proc` file system, which is almost certainly true for a Linux system, but not, e.g., for Mac OS X.

Comment: Great suggestion, /dev/tty is better but this is still a great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

IMO, if this is real world problem and not *how is it possible to do in bash*, then instead of the bash madness starting X tr and Y tee processes, you can try a simple perl oneliner:

```
echo hello | perl -nale 'foreach $i (qw(h e o)) {@F=map{s/$i//g;print $_;$_}@F}'
```

will print:

```
ello
llo
ll
```

or if your really want bash (as @chepner suggested)

```
echo "hello" | while read w; do for c in h e o; do w=${w//$c};echo $w; done;done
```

or

```
while read w; do for c in h e o; do w=${w//$c};echo $w; done;done < wordlist
```

Answer (score 2):

With a small little loop:

```
w="hello" ; for c in h e o .; do echo $w; w=$(echo $w | tr -d $c); done
```

The . is only used for a brief solution. After reading the question more carefully, I tested and found, that it works in a pipe chain too:

```
w="hello" ; for c in h e o .; do echo $w; w=$(echo $w | tr -d $c); done | less 
# pure bash buildins, see chepner's comment
w="hello" ; for c in h e o .; do echo $w; w=${w/$c}; done
```

Comment: You can replace `tr` with parameter expansion as well: `w=${w//$c}` removes all occurrences of `$c` from `$w`.

Comment: @chepner: Yes, since it is pure bash, I included it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tee -` as `-` represents the console:

```
echo "hello" | tee - | tr -d h | tee - | tr -d e | tee - | tr -d o
```

Hope that helped!

**EDIT**:

This solution **WILL NOT WORK** because `stdout` gets blocked and reused by all the commands that produce output by means of `stdout`.

I will not delete the answer as it clearly states that it doesn't solve the problem but ALSO SHOWS that this kind of solution is NOT VALID and why. If someone finds himself in the same situation will discover this information, and that will be useful.

Comment: Bizarrely, this isn't working as expected; `echo "hello" | tee - | tr -d h | tr -d e | tr -d o` is outputing "ll ll" so its the finaly output but back near the start?!

Comment: Still +1 for the use of `-` within `tee` :)

Comment: Strange! I'll take a look in a second, and try variations.

Comment: To my surprise... Right, it won't work, the stdout in blocked until the whole line is finished, and all the `tee`s get chained!!! IT WON'T WORK, THIS ANSWER DOESN'T SOLVE YOUR QUESTION. Sorry.

Comment: That cannot work because both the original as well as the copy go to stdout (fd 1) and thus are transformed by the subsequent commands.

Comment: - doesn't represent the console; it represents standard out, which may or may not be connected to the console.

Answer (score 0):

But this **WILL** work:

```
tmp=`echo "hello"`; echo $tmp; tmp=`echo $tmp | tr -d h`; echo $tmp; tmp=`echo $tmp | tr -d e`; echo $tmp; echo $C | tr -d o
```

It's ugly, but it works. The solution creates variables to store each pass and then show them all:

```
tmp=`echo "hello"`
echo $tmp
tmp=`echo $tmp | tr -d h`
echo $tmp
tmp=`echo $tmp | tr -d e`
echo $tmp
echo $C | tr -d o
```

I cannot find a better solution.

Comment: Note that this will kill all parallelism, which might be problematic for huge data chunks. If you're not echoing "hello" but a 1TB file, you're in trouble ;)

Comment: Right, but I think that is not the case: the message is "hello" and the operation is a letter substitution...

Comment: No need for process substitution: `tmp=${tmp//h}`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using a fifo (or a regular file) on which you listen:

```
mkfifo tmp.fifo
tail -f tmp.fifo
```

Then just run your command on a separate shell:

```
echo hello | tee -a tmp.fifo | tr -d e | tee -a tmp.fifo | tr -d o
```

Answer (score 0):

Room for one more?

```
echo "hello" | tee >(tr -d h | tee >(tr -d e | tee >(tr -d o) ) )
```

or

```
 echo "hello" | 
tee >(tr -d h | 
tee >(tr -d e | 
tee >(tr -d o  ) ) )
```

output is:

```
hello
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ello
llo
ll
```

a little persuasive coercion is required to eliminate corruption by `ubuntu@ubuntu:~$`

```
cat <(echo "hello" | tee >(tr -d h | tee >(tr -d e | tee >(tr -d o) ) ) )
```

output is:

```
hello
ello
llo
ll
```

Comment: short one liner - if `prompt` is null no corrosive coercion is necessary - as minimal as possible?

Comment: "no lights, no car, not a single luxury it's primitive as can be" - completely generic std IO not even console `-`